# For Open source GIS can we create a help system where every tool links to appropriate stack exchange questions?

Tags: feature-request

ArcGIS help is very good. For Open source GIS can we create a system where e.g. a help plugin for QGIS tools leads to appropriate questions on stackexchange.

This can be very helpful to new users.

Comment: If I understand your suggestion correctly, this sounds like a QGIS feature request rather than an SE feature request.  AFAIK, SE URLs are stable.  The worst that could happen is a question referenced in the QGIS help (or anywhere else) could be closed or deleted.  That seems unlikely if the thread is good enough to be used as a help page!

Comment: yes it is more like a QGIS feature request but i want to know how feasible do people think an idea like this is

Comment: For users connected to the internet, it seems like you could provide help options that search stackexchange sites (gis and others) via [the api](https://api.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Could you please post a working example? The suggestion is not clear to me.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, I don't see the advantage over typing the function or plugin name into a search engine via browser.

And if you want to "hand-pick" good SE questions, you'll need a very dedicated team. On QGIS wiki, there is a long and growing list of tutorials and video tutorials already available. GIS.SE is just one more place to answer questions. The QGIS community still provides a pretty active forum too.